# What is the default behaviour for g++ compiled code in terms of threads on an intel processor (linux)?

Tags: c++, multithreading

I understand that the answer to this question may be compiler / OS specific so I have tried to provide as much detail in the title as possible.

Say I compile a very simple loop such as the sum of all numbers from one to one million. When this code is executed on an intel processor (i7-3770k) will it take advantage of multiple threads by default? Do I stand to gain more performance by explicitly making the loop parallel?

Comment: Code for threading has to be written explicitly. But the i7 might execute code in a nonlinear way, see [out-of-order execution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Out-of-order_execution).

Comment: I didn't see anything quickly regarding threads.  But...from gcc.gnu.org "Vectorization is enabled by the flag -ftree-vectorize and by default at -O3."  So you do get vectorization without asking for it.

Answer (score 0):

C++ uses the idiom that you only pay for what you use. To enable multi-threading implicitly would penalize those that don't.  So you need to enable it yourself.

That said, in C++17 we will receive [parallel algorithms](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/execution_policy_tag_t#parallel) or you can write one - it isn't that hard.